# How to skip user sign up form presented by django-allauth when signing up through social sites?

Tags: django, django-allauth

Recently, I ran into something unusual. When i tried to sign up on my django site through Linked In it logged me in right away and redirected me to whatever the login redirect URL i had set. But now when I finnaly deployed my site on AWS, django-allauth takes me to this user sign up page asking for username before sign up. I would like to skip this and use the email instead of "username". Here are my django all auth specific settings from **settings.py**:
    `ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION  = "none"
    ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/user/"
    ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = True
    ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True`
Moreover, I have also tried setting `SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it seems that I overlooked their documentation or perhaps they recently updated it, the problem was i was using "sign up flow" to sign in an already registered user and thus allauth used to present this signup-form. You can avoid this by writing: 
 
`<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" process="login" method="oauth2" %}">`**`login with facebook`**`</a>`
and your sign up link will look like:
`<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="oauth2" %}">`**`sign up with facebook`**`</a>`
and to connect multiple accounts to same email you'll need to define an adapter like this:

```
class SocialLoginAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        # This is tested and should work
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=sociallogin.account.user.email)
            sociallogin.connect(request, user)
            # Create a response object
            response = HttpResponse()
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response)
        except Exception:
            pass
```

and do mention this in your settings.py
`SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'path_to_your_adapter_module.SocialLoginAdapter'`
And this is how my final **settings.py** looked like (allauth part)

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"  #later change to mandatory
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
# custom adapter to override login behavior and associate different social profiles with same email,with same user
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'path_to_your_adapter_module.SocialLoginAdapter'
```

Comment: what's ImmediateHttpResponse above?